# How to use `yes` with `xargs -p`?

Tags: xargs, yes

Let's say I have `ls | xargs -n1 -p rm`, how do I use `yes` or `yes n` to automatically answer the questions generated by the `-p` flag?

I tried `yes n | (ls | xargs -n1 -p rm)` but didn't work.

**UPDATE**: The question is not really about `rm`, it's about how to use `yes` properly. I have an alias or a function that uses `xargs -p` and I like the fact that it asks me and shows me what it's doing before doing it. When I know what it will do, I would like to be able to use `yes` to automatically go through all of the `xargs -p` in the function.  So even though the example uses `rm`, it's not really about it.

Also just to be extra clear, I don't want to modify my alias or function to use or not use `-p`.  I rather just input yes externally.

Tbh I thought that something like `yes | some_function_asking_me_questions` or `some_function_asking_me_questions <( yes )` would have worked, but it didn't.

**2nd EDIT**: Another example: I have an alias to list AWS SNS topics in a region like:

```sh
alias delete_snstopics="list_sns | cut -f 2 | xargs -n1 -p aws sns delete-topic --topic-arn "
```

Then I have a function that for each region in AWS finds and prompts for deletion for those SNS topics. I want to see the `aws sns delete-topic --topic-arn $1` that the xargs would run, because the id of the SNS topic is different every time and if something goes wrong I can match up the SNS id in the web console.  Moreover at times I might not want to delete the SNS topic in a particular region.  And that's why I want to use `yes` with this function, so that I can use the same function for partial deletion and full deletion, and still get useful output.  Makes sense?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to remove a single file.  Why doesn't `rm $filename` work?

Comment: either answer the xargs prompts or don't use -p?

Comment: I updated the question to make clear that this is not about `rm`, but rather about how to use `yes` with `xargs -p`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's analyse your command:

```
yes n | (ls | xargs -n1 -p rm)
```

The pipeline `ls | xargs -n1 -p rm` has `ls` reading standard input, but having standard output redirected to `xargs`, which takes it as standard input, and has its standard output unaltered.

Now you pipe the output of `yes` into this pipeline. Since the standard input of that pipeline goes into `ls`, which doesn't even read it, `xargs` cannot see any of it.

Now the obvious question is: How can `xargs` ask you whether to execute the command? After all, its standard input (where programs normally would read user interaction) is redirected to read the output of `ls`!

Well, the answer is that `xargs` bypasses the redirection mechanism for those questions by just opening the terminal file `/dev/tty` directly. Therefore the confirmation input is unaffected by file redirection.

To input to `xargs`, you need a program that can present the process with a terminal device controlled by the program. A very powerful (but also quite complicated) such program is `expect`. Unfortunately I don't know a simpler way to achieve what you want.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation.  I am not familiar with `expect`.  How much more effort would it be to to use it and make it behave like `yes` would?

Comment: would `(ls | xargs -n1 -p rm) <( yes )` not work for the same reason?  is that equivalent to `yes n | (ls | xargs -n1 -p rm)`?

Comment: @Gabriel: Unfortunately I'm not familiar with `expect` either. While answering, I actually tried to create a command with except that would do what you want, but didn't succeed; there's definitely a learning curve for it.

Comment: @Gabriel: `(ls | xargs -n1 -p rm) <( yes )` would not work either, but for a different reason: `<( yes )` is replaced by the name of a device or pipe the standard output of `yes` is connected to. But `( … )` does not not take arguments at all. That line simply gives a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ls | xargs -n1 rm -r
```

And this will work for directories or/and files.

Comment: Sorry my question apparently wasn't clear. It's not about that specific example, rather about how to use `yes` with `xargs -p`.

Comment: Ok got it, Could you make another specific example so I can help you with that?

Comment: Updated with more info and the specific example I am working on.  I am just surprised that the tool that is meant to answer questions from other cmd tools, doesn't do the job it's supposed to.  Almost all examples I saw for `yes` are for `rm` specifically, which is rather limiting.